# Ionic 2 - Convert Json date /Date()/ to string

Tags: angular, ionic2

How to convert JSON date from REST

> /Date(1480525200000+0700)/

to string format dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Comment: Note that I literally copy pasted your question title `Convert Json date /Date()/ to string` into a search engine and that dupe was in the first 5 results.

Comment: thank you. But i don't understand how to use in ionic2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myDate'
})

export class MyDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): any {
    return new Date(parseInt(value.substr(6)));
  }
}
```

then use in a template like this:

```
<div> date: {{jsonDate | myDate | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</div>
```

where `jsonDate` is your `/Date(1480525200000+0700)/`

you can see above link mentioned by @silentsod.